# Best practice to set onFocus height for a inputBox if the screen has multiple input box

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, textinput

I have many inputbox on a screen. Here I need to set scrollHeight for only one box. I have set setState value while focus on the inputbox. (Also, I have set other input box value as 0)

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need as many heights as you have TextInputs - one height in state will not solve the problem. Good approach is to wrap TextInput into your custom component that will track focused state and change height accordingly, something like this

```
class ResizingTextInput {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      focused: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...props}
        style={[props.style, { height: this.state.focused ? 50 : 10, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }]}
        onFocus={() => this.setState({ focused: true })}
        onBlur={() => this.setState({ focused: false })}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

then use `<ResizingTextInput />` instead of `<TextInput />`